# Woocommerce: relevancy based related products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Is there a way to show related products based on relevancy calculated from product titles (instead of category/tag)? I've googled for wordpress plugins, but haven't found a good solution.

Comment: have you considered using upsells/cross sells instead then you can directly pick relevant products

Comment: I prefer it automatic. I have too many products to set upsell/cross seel manually.

Comment: What, to you, would be relevancy based on post title? I think it would be difficult to program something like this, but if you know exactly what you'd like to do, nothing's impossible!

Comment: By Relevancy I mean, say product A has title "foo bar A blah", its related products should be products with similar titles e.g. "foo bar B sth sth" or "foo bar C sth sth" etc. I'm not looking to code that myself, trying my luck first if I could find an existing  solution - a good plugin.